# How to read/write into specific bits of a unsigned char

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I want to read and write from/to an unsigned char according to the table below:
[image]

for example I have following variables:

```
unsigned char hsi_div = 0x01; /* HSI/2 */
unsigned char cpu_div = 0x05; /* Fmaster/32 */
```

I want to write `hsi_div` to bits 4,3 and cpu_div to bits 2,1,0 (imagine the whole char is named CLK_DIVR):

```
CLK_DIVR |= hsi_div << 4; //not correct!
CLK_DIVR |= cpu_div << 2; //not correct!
```

And lets say I want to read the register back to make sure I did it correct:

```
if( ((CLK_DIVR << 4) - 1) & hsi_div) ) { /* SET OK */ }
if( ((CLK_DIVR << 2) - 1) & cpu_div) ) { /* SET OK */ }
```

Is there something wrong with my bitwise operations!? I do not get correct behaviour.

Comment: You want to use `uint8_t`, which is 8-bits.  The `unsigned char` is *at least 8 bits*, but could be more.

Comment: Use fixed-width types (see `stdiont.h`), not the standard integer types. And pick the language you use. C and C++ are different languages!

Comment: @ThomasMatthews it doesn't matter for the compiler and platform that I use

Comment: What behavior do you get?

Comment: That's not clear: does your check work or not? what's the problem exactly? could it be because the register is write only?

Comment: @SaeidYazdani: It is always bad style. Get used to writing self-explaining code. With `uint8_t` you would not have to explicitly mention you want to write 8 bits. Btw. Any platform providing `uint8_t` has an 8 bit wide `char`!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre the core of micro halts, the register is R/W as shown in table. I just want to make sure I am doing the bitwise operations correct or not.

Comment: @Olaf yep...removed c++ tag

Comment: @SaeidYazdani. Looks correct. I would have done in 1 time: `CLK_DIVR |= (hsi_div << 4) | (cpu_div << 2)`.

Comment: Using two RMW accesses to a `volatile` hardware register is bad design. Write the value using a single write at once.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: ... And would have had the same faults like OP in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume `CLK_DIVR` is a hardware peripheral register which should be qualified `volatile`. Such registers should be set up with as few writes as possible. You change all write-able bits, so just

```
 CLK_DIVR = (uint8_t)((hsi_div << 3) | (cpu_div << 0));
```

Note using fixed width type. That makes mentioniong it is an 8 bit register unnecessary. According to the excerpt, the upper bits are read-only, so they are not changed when writing. The cast keeps the compiler from issuing a truncation warning which is one of the recommended warnings to always enable (included in `-Wconversion` for gcc).

The shift count is actually the bit the field starts (the LSbit). A shift count of `0` means "no shifting", so the shift-operator is not required. I still use it to clarify I meant the field starts at bit `0`. Just let the compiler optimize, concentrate on writing maintainable code.

---

Note: Your code bit-or's whatever already is in the register. Bit-or can only set bits, but not clear them. Addiionally the shift counts were wrong.

---

Not sure, but if the excerpt is for an ARM Cortex-M CPU (STM32Fxxxx?), reducing external bus-cycles becomes more relevant, as the ARM can take quite some cycles for an access.

Comment: Thanks, it is STM8, I dont think its an ARM based...rather ST's own core

Comment: @SaeidYazdani: It is not an ARM. But the names are similar to those in the STM32 clock module (it just has a different layout). Was just a shot in the dark. The statements still apply. Please remember to upvote and/or accept an answer if that answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

For the HSIDIV bit fields you want:

```
hw_register = (hw_register & 0x18) | (hsi_value & 0x03) << 0x03;
```

This will mask the value to 2 bits wide then shift to bit position 3 and 4.

The CPUDIV fields are:

```
hw_register = (hw_register & 0x7) | (cpu_value & 7);
```

Reading the register:

```
hsi_value = (hw_register & 0x18) >> 3;
cpu_value = hw_register & 0x07;
```

Comment: `register` (being a keyword) is a bad name for a variable ;)

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Thanks for the reminder.  In hardware terms the thing being accessed is also called a register. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Just

```
CLK_DIVR |= hsi_div << 3;
CLK_DIVR |= cpu_div << 0;
```

Since hsi_div is a 2-digit binary, you have to move it three positions to skip the `CPUDIV` field. And the `cpu_div` is already at the end of the field.

Comment: See my answer why that is the wrong approach (multiple reasons).